# Offload CPU intensive work to background worker using REST service and Kafka

Tags: rest, asynchronous, apache-kafka, message-queue

I'm developing a REST service that takes user requests. Each user request represents a heavy calculation work. I don't want the calculation work to block the REST service. My design is to wrap user request as a task (with a unique task id) and push to Kafka. Background workers subscribe to Kafka and process any incoming tasks. The REST service saves task into database, pushes the task id to Kafka and then return immediately with the task id. User keeps polling task status with the task id.

This design is fine. But I still don't know how to deal with one scenario: if the service crashes (e.g. process down, container decommissioned) immediately after saving task into database, but before pushing task id to Kafka, then the task will never be processed.

This is an edge case that may happen rarely. But during service restart or redeployment, this might happen. So how can I make those two operations (saving to database and pushing to Kafka) atomic? Or is there any workaround to this?

Comment: Since you're using Kafka, how about implementing this with [Kafka Streams API](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/)? You don't even need a separate database then, as Kafka Streams supports stateful stream processing. State is persisted internally and failover supported through the state changelog being written to Kafka.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have a message being processed, the last thing that should happen in the process is that the message should be acknowledged. So, let's imagine the following happens in the optimal flow state:

**Nominal Flow**

1. The broker puts the message on the queue
2. The worker pulls the message
3. The worker updates the status of the task in the database
4. The worker begins calculating
5. The worker finishes calculating
6. The worker stores the result in the database
7. The worker pushes task id to Kafka *(I don't know what this does exactly)*.
8. The worker sends an acknowledgement to the broker that the message is done
9. The broker discards the successfully-processed message.

**Off-Nominal Flow**

Your question deals with a disruption between 6 and 7. If the disruption happens here, according to the nominal flow, then the acknowledgement will not be sent and the message will be replaced at the head of the queue.

What needs to be done is to adjust your nominal processing sequence between step 2 and 3. Have the worker check the database for an existing result prior to beginning the processing of the message. If the result has already been computed, it can skip to step 7 and carry on from there.